# VLC user interface is very laggy

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, gui

I'm running Windows 7 x64, with version 1.1.3 (though this started to happen a couple of versions ago). My problem is that when I'm watching a video (this doesn't happen with audio), the UI responds extremely slowly. The buttons don't turn blue when I hover over them, and clicking them only takes effect a variable number of seconds later. The slider, menus, right click menu and hotkeys all behave like this. Plus, the movie's elapsed time is updated each about 6 seconds. Also, once in a long while the video disappears for a split second and whatever window is behind it is displayed.

Just in case, I tried running an antivirus and it found a couple of things, but it still works like this. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling, to no avail. Like I said before, music works fine. This happens even without anything running in the background.

I have an AMD Triple core Phenom 8450, 4 GB of RAM and a Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS. A couple of months ago I had a different processor. Now that I think about it, it may have been around that time that VLC started misbehaving, though I can't be sure. Windows on the whole is working pretty well. It's a bit sluggish now and then, but usually everything's fine.

Comment: What are your system specs and/or make & model?

What else do you have running in the background?

Do any other applications seem sluggish?  Does windows as a whole seem sluggish?

Comment: I added the information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this lagginess could be because VLC, like Firefox, draws its own UI, instead of calling on the system to draw its UI elements. This poses a problem because the UI freezes up more since it's in the same process as the program, performance wise.

On the other hand, uninstalling VLC wouldn't do much help because VLC's configuration remains after uninstall unless you run the script in the VLC folder of the start menu to clear its options before you uninstall. Try going into the VLC folder of your start menu and looking for something that'll clear your preferences.

Comment: As of the last time I updated VLC in Windows (several months ago), the "clear previous settings" option was enabled by default. Updating VLC just uninstalls the current version before installing the new version, so reinstalling would clear the configuration unless that behavior has been changed recently.

Comment: After doing this it got a bit better. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the new processor (and possibly other hardware) did you do a clean reinstall of Windows? If you did not there might be a driver or compatibility issue because of remaining configurations from the old hardware. I would suggest doing a clean install of Windows and seeing if the issue remains.

This is probably a good course of action anyways considering you have an infected system.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but since I don't think I'm done upgrading my computer, I wanted to wait a bit and reinstall when I'm sure I'm finished.

Comment: You do not need to reinstall windows for a CPU upgrade.  The only time where a reinstall is commonly done is when a different motherboard is installed (although if it uses the same or similar chipset, you can usually avoid a reinstall).